# InvocationTargetException in jenkins machine while running selenium RemoteWebdriver

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I made a setup to run selenium scripts during jenkins build. Jenkins is available in linux machine and selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar is running in the jenkins machine.

The selenium grid will run the scripts in windows machine and the code looks like,

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        desiredCapabilities.setBrowserName("chrome");
        desiredCapabilities.setPlatform(Platform.ANY);

        WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://example.com:5555/wd/hub"), desiredCapabilities);
```

I also have the below setup in jenkins,

[image]

maven is used to run the selenium test suite and the junit test report are published.

Sometime the jenkins machine is going down with the below error,

```
Jun 24, 2015 4:15:57 AM hudson.node_monitors.ResponseTimeMonitor$1 monitor
WARNING: Making NewSlave offline because it’s not responding
Jun 24, 2015 4:44:04 AM hudson.ExpressionFactory2$JexlExpression evaluate
WARNING: Caught exception evaluating: it.transientActions in /job/Selenium_GRID/4/console. Reason: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    .....
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.chikli.hudson.plugin.naginator.NaginatorActionFactory.createFor(NaginatorActionFactory.java:20)
    at hudson.model.Run.getTransientActions(Run.java:362)
    ... 122 more
Jun 24, 2015 5:15:42 AM hudson.model.Run execute
```

This is the selenium server log,

```
Jun 22, 2015 6:46:04 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy isAlive
WARNING: Failed to check status of node: Connection refused
Jun 22, 2015 6:47:12 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy isAlive
WARNING: Failed to check status of node: Connection timed out
Jun 22, 2015 6:47:12 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy onEvent
WARNING: Marking the node as down. Cannot reach the node for 2 tries.
Jun 22, 2015 6:48:20 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy isAlive
WARNING: Failed to check status of node: Connection refused
Jun 22, 2015 6:48:20 PM org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy onEvent
WARNING: Unregistering the node. It's been down for 67828 milliseconds.
Jun 22, 2015 6:48:20 PM org.openqa.grid.internal.Registry removeIfPresent
WARNING: Proxy 'host :http://xxx.xxx.y.z:5555' was previously registered.  Cleaning up any stale test sessions.
```

The problem is that, jenkins is going down when the selenium scripts got failed or sometimes when viewing the failed test results in jenkins test report.Can anyone please suggest why this issue is occuring and how to resolve this issue?
 Is this issue occuring due to the selenium server running in jenkins machine or any other reason?